# hiding all the gride included space title and column

Tags: extjs4.2

I work with extjs 4.2 and I want to hide a gride

but with my code I can juste hide a colonne and title of gride but not the space of gride

I try with this code :

```
     var myPanel= Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {id:'test',store: testStore,         collapsible:true,hidden: true,title:listRequestUPRegist,
columns: [{xtype: 'checkcolumn', hidden: true,header: 'test',dataIndex: 'checked',  width:
     60,listeners:{'checkchange': RequestGridSelectionChanged}}             
],
columnLines: true,  
anchor: '100%',
 frame: true, 
height: 250, 
//margin: '5 5 5 5', 
        dockedItems: [{

            xtype: 'toolbar',
                            dock: 'bottom',
                            ui: 'footer',
                            layout: {
                            pack: 'center'
                            },
                            items: [
                                { 
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    text: consultation,

                                } 
                                ]
                            }]
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be problem with layout you are using. Please change that layout type. I think you are fit layout. Try changing layout type as auto.